# From where knows [authorize] the roles / users (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm a newbie to asp.net mvc, so I created a simple internet application from the template. I added some user and some roles and connected them (in database). Then I added [authorize(Roles = "MyRole")] and everything works fine. Can anyone tell me from where authorize takes the information about users and roles and so on? Where is the magic that wired that up? (As I said: simple application from template mvc 5 "internet application")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any magic here. Once you've authenticated, a principal is registered and filled with some of the basic information for the user, including any roles they're associated with. This information ultimately comes from your database of course, but how the authorization layer retrieves that and implements the principal from it is low-level and dependent ultimately on the authentication provider being used (Membership, Identity, Windows Auth, etc.).

Regardless, the `Authorize` attribute merely looks at the roles on the principal and if there's a match, allows the action to proceed. Otherwise, it does a redirect, usually to the sign in page of the application, or returns a 401 Not Authorized, depending on whether the user is authenticated or anonymous.